# Facebook Graph API will not give me picture data

Tags: php, facebook, graph

Using PHP 5.2.11 and the new facebook graph code...

If I call

$facebook->api("/me");

I get a proper response:

```
array
  'id' => string '10700210' (length=8)
  'name' => string 'Brandon Renfrow' (length=19)
  'first_name' => string 'Brandon' (length=7)
  'middle_name' => string 'âœ«' (length=3)
  'last_name' => string 'Renfrow' (length=7)
  'link' => string 'http://www.facebook.com/brenfrow' (length=32)
  'about' => string 'Spiritual birthday: 1/22/2005' (length=29)
  ...
  ...
```

But if I call

```
$facebook->api("/me/picture");
```

I always get a response of:

```
null
```

Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well I guess the best answer I've found is to call http://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID?fields=picture to get the picture URL. Its to bad they don't document things like this on their API especially when its obvious this is broken for so many people.

Comment: Thanks for figuring this out. The Facebook Graph API is probably one of the worst designed and even more worse documented API I ever had to work with.

Answer (score 8):

As an addition to [betaman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546975/betaman)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978761/facebook-graph-api-will-not-give-me-picture-data/4636907#4636907), you can pass the parameters in a separate array like so:

```
$aResponse = $oFacebook->api('/me', array(
    'fields' => 'picture',
    'type' => 'large'
));
```

Comment: It will only return the small image.

Comment: That must be new.  It certainly worked that way when I posted this.

Comment: Yes, it is new. Check http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/129804577163441. Now you have to specify type like this:
'fields' => 'picture.type(normal)'

Answer (score 7):

You may not even need to do an API call... use this on your frontend:

```
<img src="//graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/picture?type=square" />
```

Read more here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#pictures

Comment: I just read this old post randomly today and this is the answer to something ive been pondering for awhile

Comment: This works well but adds latency while the image path is resolved through a redirect.

Answer (score 3):

There is an even simpler way, using the provided facebook api,  just call:

`$facebook->api("/me?fields=picture");`

This will make your code simpler and more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

While using $facebook->api("/me?fields=picture"); does work, you won't be able to pass parameters such as width or type. Instead try the following:

```
$facebook->api('/me/picture?redirect=false');
```

This worked for me and will also allow you to pass parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I just went to my "/me/picture" in the browser and it redirected me to a static image on one of Facebook's CDN servers. Perhaps the redirect is throwing a wrench in your api call.