# FBRequest: Why aren't non-text mime type responses allowed? (iOS SDK)

Tags: image, facebook-ios-sdk

Using the Facebook iOS SDK, let's say I perform a graph request for the user's profile picture:

```
[FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"me/picture"]
```

I'll receive this error:

```
Response is a non-text MIME type; endpoints that return images and other binary data should be fetched using `NSURLRequest` and `NSURLConnection`.
```

What is the reasoning behind this? It only took a minute to write the request manually but why isn't this common task included in the Facebook iOS SDK or am I missing something?

Looking through the Facebook iOS SDK repo on Github, we see this in `FBRequestConnection.m`:

```
if (!error && [response.MIMEType hasPrefix:@"image"]) {
        error = [self errorWithCode:FBErrorNonTextMimeTypeReturned
                         statusCode:0
                 parsedJSONResponse:nil
                         innerError:nil
                            message:@"Response is a non-text MIME type; endpoints that return images and other "
                                    @"binary data should be fetched using NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection"];
    }
```

If I'm understanding this correctly, `FBRequestConnection` gets the response I want (i.e. the profile image) and THEN tells me I can't have it. What a tease. Why make the request in the first place?

Any comments on this?

Answer (score 5):

For large picture

`me?fields=picture.type(large)`

Refer to [Facebook Graph API Change: Picture type (size) no longer working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982276/facebook-graph-api-change-picture-type-size-no-longer-working)

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to ask for a specific field instead of the picture (found here: [Facebook Graph API will not give me picture data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978761/facebook-graph-api-will-not-give-me-picture-data))

So use

```
[FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"me?fields=picture"]
```

That should work

Comment: How do you grab the picture from the data that's given back from this? I get a big chunk of braces and stuff and it doesn't work just to try and form a dictionary from it... I get something like the stuff below:

(         {         body =         {             id = 100002899999999;             picture =             {                 data =                 {                     "is_silhouette" = 0;                     url = "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc6/623595_199999892043363_26625455_q.jpg";                 };             };         };         code = 200;     } )

Comment: NEvermind, I got it. But I'm still not entirely sure how to get a large picture instead of a small one.